# Give collaborator admin rights on github

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project with a friend, so I created a repository where he's "collaborator". Thing is, he can't push anything to the repo because he doesn't have access as an admin should.

I don't know if you can change the collaborator rights in order for him to push code, I found earlier that, as collaborator, he should already have those rights to push but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Can you explain me why, and maybe give me a solution for him to push please ?

Comment: is your repo public or private? is it linked to your user account or organization?

Comment: it's linked to my user account and it's public

Comment: Can you elaborate on "can't push"? What steps does he follow, and what error does he get?

Comment: When he presses the "push" button on VsCode, he gets an error :"You dont have access rights to push on <ProjectNameRepository>, would you create a fork in order to do so"